# if statement not working in my JS snake game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a snake game in JS. Right now I'm trying to write a condition that compares the position of the snake head and the position of the food to see if the snake has made contact with it. If so I want to alert the user. Except the condition isn't working for some reason. I've made another version of this game and I used the same condition in that one, so this is really confusing Any ideas?

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create food object and set its position somewhere on board
let food = {
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW + 1)---number from 1 to 784
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)---number from 1 to 79
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)*unit---number from 1 to 784(but it's a multiple of unit)
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit---same as above but -1 keeps food inside canvas
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit
}

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})

function draw() {
 //clear canvas and redraw snake and food
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
 ctx.fillRect(snake[0].x-unit/2, snake[0].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //move snake in chosen direction
 changeDirection();

 //check to see if snakes eaten
 if(snake[0].x === food.x && snake[0].y === food.y) {
  alert('yo');
 }

 //check to see if snake has hit a wall
 collision(snake[0].x, snake[0].y);
}


let runGame = setInterval(draw, 70);

function changeDirection() {
 if(direction == 'left') snake[0].x -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') snake[0].x += unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') snake[0].y -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') snake[0].y += unit;
}


function collision(x, y) {
 if(x < 0 || x > cvsW || y < 0 || y > cvsH) {
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  #canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="784" height="528"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, I would think is it probably a problem with using the unit of 16. You are testing for exact match rather than collision. If that makes sense.

Comment: Not really:( My code is almost an exact replica of another version of this game I made this morning. I use 16 units in that version as well as the same if statement. http://jsfiddle.net/L10mh8ey/4/

Comment: Check your start point of the snack, log it out. And Log our the food location. Then work out if the snake will ever be able to exactly match that number.

Comment: It looks like the snake will always be 8 units more on the x and y position. I think I know why that is. If you look at that fiddle link on my previous version I use `ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);` to draw the snake. It was pointed out to me that the snake is not centered exactly, you can't really see it but since the canvas draws starting at the top left i was suggested to try this instead `ctx.fillRect(snake[0].x-unit/2, snake[0].y-unit/2, unit, unit);` This will shift it up 8 units and left 8 units. I thought a simple fix would be to add the -unit/2 to the part that

Comment: draws the food `ctx.fillRect(food.x-unit/2, food.y-unit/2, unit, unit);` this doesn't work though, any ideas

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be here

```
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
    else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
    else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
    else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})
```

In this case the direction is `undefined` so no value will be assigned the `direction`

Comment: No direction is not undefined, if it was you wouldn't be able to move the snake. Hit an arrow key to start the game then move over the food